# Who to follow suggestions function in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

So my model Users has two fields that looks exactly like this:

```
following: [
  {
    friendship: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Friendship'
    },
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    }
  }
],
followers: [
  {
    friendship: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Friendship'
    },
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    }
  }
]
```

I have function that is supposed to 'suggest' to the loggedIn accounts users to follow. This is the function:

```
exports.whoToFollow = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const people = await User.find()
    .merge({
      _id: { $nin: req.user._id },
      followers: { $nin: { user: req.user._id } }
    })
    .select(`username avatar name`)
    .limit(6);
  res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: people });
});
```

The first line in the merge is to avoid showing the loggedIn account, the line after that is where I'm having troubles.
It is supposed to give me the users I have not yet followed but it always displays the users I have already followed also, a bit confusing lol.

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it!!:

```
exports.whoToFollow = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const people = await User.find()
    .merge({
      _id: { $nin: req.user._id },
      'followers.user': { $nin: req.user._id }
    })
    .select(`username avatar name`)
    .limit(6);
  res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: people });
});
```

I just needed to use dot notation lol.